# Ruby / Rails: How to get an object from an array with attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My question is very simple, I have:

```
@users = User.first(100)
```

From the **@users** array, how can i get the user object with the id **50**?

Answer (score 2):

Use [detect](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/detect):

```
user = @users.detect { |u| u.id == 50 }
```

Though there are [ways](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class) to fetch just one record (with id 50) if you don't need the remaining 99.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you think your answer is better? I've never read about detect.

Comment: You should check the link to its documentation. I don't know about `@users.find`, how it works. But `detect` will iterate over the `@users` and when first element with matching condition is found, loop breaks and that element is returned.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do an `ActiveRecord` find you can do:

```
@users = User.find_by_id(50)
```

Or if you want to do an `Array` find you can do:

```
@users.find_all { |user| user.id == 50 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is very close of how I get it. Do you think your answer is better?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution myself, but I'll wait until other people tell us which answer is better.

```
@users.find {|u| u.id == 50 }
```

Thanks for your answers!